# 3 Phase breaker - Current Limit

Tags: three-phase, current-limiting, circuit-breaker

I have a simple question... If I have this 3 Phase breaker:[image]

That means its current limit is 20A right? **My question is, is it limit for the whole breaker or limit for every phase separately?**... What Iam trying to do is to connect three 2kW cookers, so total of 6kW power. So when it would be for whole breaker the maximum power would be 230x20=4600W that is too low... and when it would be for each phase it would be 3x(230x20)=13800W

Thanks a lot...
Jirka

Comment: There is a steel rod though them to form a three phase group. If any one phase is over the trip current, that will force the other two to trip as well.

Comment: Here is 3 separate breakers. Tripping one of them cause disconnect all 3 circuit.

Comment: As your cookers are single-phase check your local wiring regulations to see if you need to replace your 3-phase breaker with 3 single-phase breakers and associated wiring changes e.g. extra neutrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That means its current limit is 20A right?

That means each phase has a 20 A trip level.

> What I am trying to do is to connect three 2 kW cookers, so total of 6 kW. So when ... it would be for each phase it would be 3 × 230 × 20 = 13800 W

Correct.

2 kW on a 230 V supply should draw 2000 / 230 = 8.7 A. If you balance the loads across the phases you should be fine. Don't forget that you need to connect between phase and neutral.